# Declare MVC Model in jquery and pass as data parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to declare model in jquery and pass as POST parameters in $.ajax?

I have model like

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public Role RoleDetail {get;set;}
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId {get;set;}
}
```

and in js, something like this

```
function postData(id)
{
  @{ var model = new UserDetail{ Role = new Role{ RoleId =  id};

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: ...
     data: JSON.stringify(model)
  });
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be possible. Reason being Mvc is a server side technology where as javascript is client side. So calling server side method in client side is clearly not possible.

Unless you create a ActionResult in Mvc which accept id and return the object - then you call it by ajax before posting, so something like:

```
function postData(id)
{
    $.getJSON("CreateUserDetail?id=" + id, function( model ) {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ...
         data: JSON.stringify(model)
      });
     })    
}
```

But in my opinion, it is waste of bandwidth, why not just construct it in client side, so something like:

```
function postData(id)
{
  var model = {"RoleDetail":{ "RoleId": id}};

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: ...
     data: JSON.stringify(model)
  });
}
```